# Get values from a listbox on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a listbox named ListBox1 on Sheet1 of an Excel workbook.

Every time the user selects one of the items in the list, I need to copy its name to a variable named strLB.

So, if I have Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4 and the user selects Value1 and Value3, I need my strLB to come out as Value1,Value3.

I tried doing that *post hoc* with:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("ListBox1").ListCount
    If ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("ListBox1").Selected(i) Then strLB = strLB & etc.etc.
Next i
```

But this is very slow (I have 15k values in my listbox). This is why I need to record the selection in real time and not in a cycle, after the user is done inputting.

I'm going to also need a way to check if the user removed any of the previous selection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately for MSForms list box looping through the list items and checking their Selected property is the only way. However, here is an alternative. I am storing/removing the selected item in a variable, you can do this in some remote cell and keep track of it :)

```
Dim StrSelection As String

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    If ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) Then
        If StrSelection = "" Then
            StrSelection = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
        Else
            StrSelection = StrSelection & "," & ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
        End If
    Else
        StrSelection = Replace(StrSelection, "," & ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex), "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and see if I can come up with some working code! Thanks man!

Comment: I can't seem to find the equivalent of `.ListIndex` for a listbox that's not in a userform. I'm stuck at `ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("ListBox1").list(ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("ListBox1").ListIndex)`, it doesn't work this way...

Comment: How are you adding the listbox? Is it an ActiveX Control?

Comment: It's actually a Form Control I selected from Deleveloper Tab -> Insert -> Form Controls. Should I use the ActiveX kind instead?

Comment: Ah! You will have to use an AciveX Control for the above :)

Comment: Actually, I have three more issues! Number 1: the list of items that the listbox shows varies with a dynamic range. When the range turns completely blank though, the listbox still shows the last list of items. I want my list to go blank just as the underlying range does. How do I do that? Number two: there's some empty lines in the list, after all the values. How do I prevent those empty lines from being clickable? Number three: I put a second  listbox on my sheet, now when I select an item on one of those, the selection on the other disappears. I can't "Cross-Select" this way!

Comment: I am out at the moment. Will be back in an hour. Will look at it then :) posting from BB.

Comment: Ok, fixed problem 1 and 2 with    

 `ActiveSheet.ListBox2.ListFillRange = ""
    ActiveSheet.ListBox2.ListFillRange = "=NamedRangeName"` this blanks the list and repopulates it all the times so now it works properly. Still, I can't make selections on one listbox without erasing the selections on the other one.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem, When I select items in both, then both show as highlighted?

Comment: I forgot to tell you that mine are multiple selection enabled listboxes. As soon as I click listbox number 2 all the fields I highlighted in listbox number 1 get deselected...

Comment: It doesn't happen with me. See this screenshot http://wikisend.com/download/466786/Untitled.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9208/discussion-between-bruder-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829798/selection-in-listbox-on-an-excel-worksheet-goes-blank-everytime-i-do-something) on this as it seems to be a little more complicated than i thought.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer doesn't cut it because if a user de-selects a row the list is not updated accordingly.

Here is what I suggest instead:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim lItem As Long

    For lItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(lItem) = True Then
            MsgBox(ListBox1.List(lItem))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Courtesy of http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/multi-select-listbox.htm

Comment: As far as I can tell, the accepted answer does take care of that as well --> StrSelection = Replace(StrSelection, "," & ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex), "")

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of the selected item of a listbox then use the following.

For Single Column ListBox:
`ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)`

For Multi Column ListBox:
`ListBox1.Column(column_number, ListBox1.ListIndex)`

This avoids looping and is extremely more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Take selected value:**

```
worksheet name = ordls
form control list box name = DEPDB1

selectvalue = ordls.Shapes("DEPDB1").ControlFormat.List(ordls.Shapes("DEPDB1").ControlFormat.Value)
```