# Selection in ListBox on an Excel worksheet goes blank everytime I do something, why?

Tags: events, excel, listbox, vba

So, I have an ActiveX ListBox control named ListBox1 on Sheet1 of my Excel Workbook. I enabled multiple selections on it.

I also put some code in the Sheet1 Object:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Debug.Print "hello world"
End Sub
```

Now, if I select three values in my listbox, I see "Hello world" three times in my immediate window. So I guess the Change event triggers correctly.

When I select any cell on the same sheet where my listbox is, and I do something with it (e.g. I type "ABCDE" in it, or I press *Delete*) the selection I made in the listbox goes blank.

So if I had the first value in the list selected, and then I click cell "A1", type "Hello" in it and press *Enter*, the very moment I hit the key the first value is unselected from the listbox.

Why the hell is this? This is driving me crazy. Is the Listbox1_Change event not working properly?

It's funny though, because I don't see an extra "Hello world" in the immediate window, so I guess the event didn't actually trigger...

Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruder

As I mentioned earlier this is because the `.Listfillrange` for both the ListBox is resetting automatically.

You have specified a named range for your `.Listfillrange` and the formula for the named range is

For `FiltroCliente`

```
=IF(CollClientePicker<>1,OFFSET(DatiMaschera!$D$2,0,0,COUNTA(DatiMaschera!$D:$D)-1,1),"")
```

Now when you are making any change, Excel is re-calculating the named range because of which the `.Listfillrange` gets automatically updated.

Here is another way to check it.

Scroll your Listbox1 and select an item and then select an item in Listbox2. You will notice that the Listbox1 automatically scrolls to the top because it's `.Listfillrange` gets automatically updated.

**SOLUTION**

Instead of a Named Range in `.Listfillrange`, automatically fill the listbox using `.Additem`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
'~~> Example : Add values from Cell A1:A10
For i = 1 To 10
    ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
Next i
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: You're the magic one Sid. I thought I could use this instead of a dynamic range, but I feared that filling a list of 15k items would take too much time. It's fast as lightning instead! Thanks man!