# Display clicked List Box value in cell

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a **Form Control** list box with multiple items.

I would like a certain cell on the worksheet to display the contents of the list box item the user selects and change if the user makes a different selection.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already know how to write to a cell:

```
Set TxtRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Range("A1")
TxtRng.Value = "Your Text Here"
```

And the following piece of code would go into your **ListBoxChanged-Event**, so the cell displays the new value every time a new value has been selected in the List Box.

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        SelectedItemText = ListBox1.List(i)
    End If
Next i
'Set the value of the cell to the selected item.
TxtRng.Value = SelectedItemText
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I should have mentioned this is a FORM CONTROL listbox actually embedded in the workbook.  Not a Userform.

Comment: Oh Alright. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821968/vba-to-get-values-from-a-listbox-on-a-spreadsheet-in-excel). Here the asker needs another solution because of an performance issue. Unless you don't have 15k entries in your list box following should work fine     

    _For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("ListBox1").ListCount
        If ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("ListBox1").Selected(i) Then strLB = strLB & etc.etc.
    Next i_
Maybe you also need to use something like this
_ActiveSheet.Shapes("List Box 4").ControlFormat.List_