# vba listbox value matches list

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a user form where they should pick a supplier from a table in the worksheet and when they press the "ShowProducts" command, the form should show all the articles from this supplier in the textbox below.

I made the following code but it keeps giving me an error on the line `If Suppl.Value = Me.LstB_Supplier.Value Then`.

I have searched and tried different options I have found on this and other sites, but I can't seem to find what it wrong.

Can anyone help me out?  Thanks!

```
Private Sub Cmd_ShowProducts_Click()

    Dim Suppl As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each Suppl In Range("T_Prod_Fix[Supplier Name]")
        If Suppl.Value = Me.LstB_Supplier.Value Then
             With Me.LstB_Products
                 .AddItem
                 .List(i, 0) = Suppl.Offset(0, 1).Value   'article nbr
                 .List(i, 1) = Suppl.Offset(0, -1).Value  'article name
                 i = i + 1
             End With
          End If
     Next Suppl

End Sub
```

Comment: id `LstB_Supplier` a `TextBox` or a `ListBox` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check, whether a value, selected in a list box is present in another list, you need a nested loop. With the first loop you get the selected value and with the inner loop you need to check whether it exists in your range.

E.g. in your case:

```
For lItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then 'Check for selection
        For Each suppl In Range("T_Prod_Fix[Supplier Name]")
            If suppl = ListBox1(lItem) Then
                'your logic
            End If
        Next suppl
    End If
Next lItem
```

Related: [VBA to get values from a listbox on a spreadsheet in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821968/vba-to-get-values-from-a-listbox-on-a-spreadsheet-in-excel)

Comment: thanks, that gets me a lot further.  Now I am stuck with one more thing:
Suppl = ListBox1(lItem)
suppl is defined as a range, but listbox1(lItem) is a string so i get a type mismatch.  If I define suppl as a string, i get the next error: "For each control variable must be variant or object". I'll search again in this forum to find an answer to that.

Comment: Try defining suppl as `Object` or as `Variant`, as it says.