# Selected Listbox Item error

Tags: vba, excel

I want to set the value from a listbox into a cell but when I select the item, the cells receives the value FALSE

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
ActiveCell.Value = ListBox1.Selected(Item)
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Item`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821968/vba-to-get-values-from-a-listbox-on-a-spreadsheet-in-excel

Comment: `ListBox.Selected` returns a `Boolean` that tells you whether the item at the specified index is selected or not. So, `ListBox1.Selected(Item)` is not selected.